# Como migrar de NotificationManager para NotificationCompat na API 23

Tags: android

conforme o titulo, estou que esse problema. Sou novato nisso e não estou conseguindo migrar para API 23 (NotificationCompat). Poderiam me ajudar?

Segue meu código:

```
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onStart");
        mp.start();
        // Set the isPlaying preference to true
        editor.putBoolean("isPlaying", true);
        editor.commit();

        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        String notifTitle = context.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name);
        String notifMessage = context.getResources().getString(R.string.now_playing);

        n.icon = R.mipmap.ic_launcher;
        n.tickerText = notifMessage;
        n.flags = Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;
        n.when = System.currentTimeMillis();

        Intent nIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, nIntent, 0);

        n.NotificationManager(context, notifTitle, notifMessage, pIntent);
        // Change 5315 to some nother number
        notificationManager.notify(notifId, n);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy");
        mp.stop();
        mp.release();
        mp = null;
        editor.putBoolean("isPlaying", false);
        editor.commit();
        notificationManager.cancel(notifId);
    }

}
```

Comment: qual é o erro que você está tendo? tem um Log, algo que facilite o entendimento?

Comment: Está retornando erro na linha:  n.NotificationManager(context, notifTitle, notifMessage, pIntent);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Troque

```
 n.NotificationManager(context, notifTitle, notifMessage, pIntent);
```

por :

```
   n.setContentIntent(pIntent);
```

para passar o `PendingIntent` para o seu `Notification.Builder`

Comment: Persiste ainda: Error:(63, 10) error: cannot find symbol method setContentIntent(PendingIntent)